# Prove/provide a counter example that if $f$ is injective then then $f_*$ is injective

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $X,\, Y$ be sets and  $f:X\to Y$ be a function. Then $f$ induces a function $f_*:\mathcal P(X)\to \mathcal P(Y)$, defined by
$$f_*(A):=f(A)=\{f(x)\, |\, x\in A\}\subseteq Y,\quad \forall A\subseteq X.$$
 Prove or find a counterexample to the statement: if $f$ is injective, then $f_*$ is injective.

I know that I need to show that if we have $x$ and $x_1$ $\in X$ such that $f_*(x)=f_*(x_1)$ then $x=x_1$ must be true. I just don't really know where to start. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose $f_*(A)=f_*(B),$ then $$\{f(x):x\in A\}=\{f(y):y\in B\},$$ so pick $x_1\in A$ such that $f(x_1)\in f_*(A),$ conclude that there should exists some $y_1\in B$ such that $f(x_1)=f(y_1).$**Why?**  and use injectivity of $f.$